# What kind of hashing is GF multiplication in GCM cipher mode and GMAC?

Tags: hash, authenticated-encryption, gcm, aes-gcm

In GCM, GMAC, the additional associated data (AAD) (as well as outputs of subsequent blocks) is multiplied by a polynomial H in GF(2^128). This appears to be doing some secure hashing.

Is that what's happening, and if so, is this a general hashing method that's used elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In GCM, GMAC, the additional associated data (AAD) (as well as outputs of subsequent blocks) is multiplied by a polynomial H in GF(2^128).

Actually, it's the other way around; the AAD and the ciphertext is converted into a polynomial, and that polynomial is evaluated at a secret point H (in $GF(2^{128})$

> This appears to be doing some secure hashing.

Nope, no secure hashing here; if someone knows what $H$ is, they can easily find collisions, preimages, etc.  Hence, a full specification of the algorithm (including $H$) is not secure.

This is, instead, a similar sounding object known as an 'almost universal hash'; what that means is that, for any two distinct messages, they get mapped to the same point for only a tiny fraction of the keys (which is the $H$ value here) [1]

That's the sole property that an almost universal hash needs to satisfy; note that it may be easy (for example) to deduce the value $H$ by submitting a message and examining the hash value.  Hence, by itself, it doesn't meet the criteria of a secure hash.

What are almost universal hashes good for?  Well, they can be used as a component in a Message Authentication Code - in essence, the almost universal hash processes the message (based on a secret key), and then some object with real cryptographical properties (in the case of GCM/GMAC, AES) disguises that hash.  This is known as the Carter Wegman construction, and is in common use (Poly1305 would be a second example).

And, one good thing about almost universal hashes is that we have constructions (of which GH is one) which provably meets the criteria.

[1]: Actually, for how GH is used within GCM/GMAC, you need a slightly stronger property; we'll skip this for now.